# Compiling vb project using VBC throwing error

Tags: command-line, vb6, vb6-migration, xp-mode, vbc

I have VB project, which is compiling/building perfectly using vb6 IDE in XP mode.

My objective is to automate the deployment process, so am trying to build this project in command line using VBC.

But while compiling vb project in window 7 using VBC.exe and cmd its throwing following error/exception.

Example:
**error: BC30203: Identifier expected.

error: BC30481:'class' statement must end with matching end class.

error: BC30617:'Module' statement can occur only at file or namespace level.**

Does anybody have any suggestion ideas what am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `vbc` you are using is not .Net compiler for VB.Net?

Comment: NO ,. how to find it ?

Comment: The VB6 Compiler was named C2.EXE

Comment: See `vb6.exe /?` E.g. `vb6.exe /make proj.vbp`

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to compile a VB6 project using the VB.NET compiler